# Swiftlint allow force unwrap for hardcoded URLs while maintaining force_unwrapping rule

Tags: swift, swiftlint

In my iOS porjects i use Swiftlint with the rule "force_unwrapping". But every time i need to hardcode a URL i'd like to simply force unwrap it.

Is there a configuration for Swiftlint to allow such cases? Currently i simply disable and re-enable the rule around this code.

```swift
Link("Google", destination: URL(string: "https://www.google.com)")!) // throws force_unwrapping warning
```

Comment: Create an extension init, e.g. `URL.init(correctString: StringLiteral)`, put force unwrapping there with a single `swiftlint:disable:next force_unwrapping` and use that method where needed.

Comment: @Sulthan could you provide an answer with such an extension so i can accept it?

Comment: Of course, I was on mobile so I just put a quick comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to put the unwrapping to a single place and disable swiftlint on that single place:

For example:

```
public extension URL {
    init(safeString: String) {
        // swiftlint:disable:next force_unwrapping
        self.init(string: safeString)!
    }
}
```

Then you can use `URL(safeString: "https://www.google.com")` without problems.
Of course, you don't need to necessarily use forced unwrapping, you could also throw a `fatalError`.

However, note that with expression macros coming in Swift 5.9 (Xcode 15), you can actually write a macro that will validate your URL at compilation time, e.g.

```
#URL("https://swift.org/")
```

You can find it in [swift-macro-examples](https://github.com/DougGregor/swift-macro-examples) repo.

Comment: Oh the macro approach looks interesting. My issue with the first implementation is that one can parse in a string variable, but i'd like to limit it to hard coded strings.

Comment: @Deitsch You can limit it to `StaticString` but the conversion `StaticString` -> `String` is not that simple.